# Gas cost / ETH fee in order to send Golem?

Tags: gas, tokens, myetherwallet, gas-price, gas-estimate

I want to send Golem from myetherwallet to a friends wallet.

How much does the Ethereum network charge in gas / ETH fee for sending a token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an exact answer, but the amount is very small.  I just sent a bundle of GNT and the gas cost was $.06 worth of eth.

Comment: A bundle like lets say over $10 worth of Golem? How quickly did the transaction take to clear (be confirmed)?

Comment: Much more than $10 worth.  I had no problem with quick confirmations.

Comment: So for tokens its under 1%. Exactly what I was curious about. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's going to be way under 1%.